# Can't set focus to tinyMCE textarea on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, tinymce

I need use to be able to use multiple [tinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com) `<textarea>`s on an iPad compatible site.

However when I view [the site example website](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/multiple_configs.php) on my iPad, I can't get it to focus on the 2nd `<textarea>`.

Comment: If tinyMCE's example is not working, it's probably not going to work.

Comment: Thx for your help, I think this is the ios issue, but it was not supported by tinyMCE.

Answer (score 1):

Programatically, you may use `tinymce.get('your_editor_id').focus()` to focus your editor.
What you see as editor is not a a textarea, but a contenteditable iframe.